# OData query failing at filtering data

Tags: filter, odata

I am trying get few records by filtering odata using a filter where status not equals to bad and poor and id= 105 and id= 106

http://mywebsite.com/testService.svc/Details?$top=10&$filter=(Status ne 'Bad' and Status ne 'poor' and Id eq 105 and Id eq 106)

What was my mistake this show 0 records even there are related records. Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming that your `ID` property is a primary key. So there will never be a data set that matches both IDs but you are searching for it with `and`. Try to change your query to:

```
http://mywebsite.com/testService.svc/Details?$top=10&$filter=(Status ne 'Bad' and Status ne 'poor' and (Id eq 105 or Id eq 106))
```